# Use a variable in multiple modules

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bit of code and a few modules that I would like to access the variables in.

in my start module I am declaring the variables as "Public" - this is what i hoped that would let me access the variables in different modules...

```
Option Explicit
Public Ttermanf, Ttermend, Date2, DateN, Ttermeld  As Date
Public ft, mainb_ret, swp, Tmod, Tsub4, Tslz4 As String
```

Then I call up a userform from my start module

```
Form1.show
```

On the userform are a bunch of Textboxes, dropdowns etc.. the usual stuff, all working so far...

When I click "button1" it calls different modules - I was trying to split the code so my code on the form is not so long, thus grouping things logically.

```
call header_m
```

in this module I would like to have the value of Ttermend, but to my surprise it is empty ....

In the main form the values are there, but as soon as I jump into another module they are blank...

suggestions ? I tried using global, but same thing.

Why ? I thought by declaring it as public it should be available in any module ? not so ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the Dims are in a standard module
2. Make sure the Dims precede any Subs or Functions
3. Make sure the variables are assigned values before they are used
4. Fix your Dim syntax:

use:

```
Dim a As String, b As String, c As String
```

rather then

```
Dim a, b, c As String
```

Comment: Hi, tx for this. The weird thing is, if I take the code out of the module and paste it straight back into the userform (in place of the call... ) everything works hunky dory fine. I tried passing the variable to the module `call header_m(Ttermend)` but no cigar either.

Comment: Just created a blank simple workbook and in there it works as expected. Still do not understand why the original one does not work. If i do a MsgBox to show the value just before calling the module, the value is assigned. In the module, first thing is a MsgBox for the same value and it is blank.. weird.. I´ll go hunting some more.